# Why does destructuring props in react with Typescript function require passing an object?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have recently started using react with typescript and it seems like something odd is happening when I destructure props with optional / default values. For example take this function to generate a random id:

```
interface GenKeyIdProps {
  length?: number;
}

/**
 * Generate a random id (mainly for use with rendering lists of components.
 * genKeyId convert Math.random to base 36 (numbers + letters), and grab the first ${lenght} characters after the decimal.
 * @param length (optional) specify how many characters the id should be. default is 5.
 * @returns a string with number and letters of specified length.
 */
export const genKeyId = ({ length = 5 }: GenKeyIdProps) => Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, length);
```

The problem is when I try to call it:

```
import { genKeyId } from '../../../helpers';

interface TextWrapperProps {
  textLines: string[];
}

const TextWrapper = ({ textLines }: TextWrapperProps) => {

  return textLines.map(line => (<div key={genKeyId()}>{line}</div>));

};

export default TextWrapper;
```

if I do not pass at least an empty object to genKeyId I get the following error: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554).

Why do I need to pass an empty object? Is my GenKeyIdProps interface specifying the props need to be part of an object? I am a bit confused about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my GenKeyIdProps interface specifying the props need to be part of an object?

Yes, you've defined `GenKeyIdProps` as an object. All `interface` definitions are objects. Your `GenKeyIdProps` is roughly equivalent to:

```typescript
type GenKeyIdProps = {
  length?: number;
};
```

That is, an object with an optional `length` property of type `number`.

There's no need for `genKeyId` to accept an object, though; it's not a component function, it's just a utility function. You could define it to accept `length` directly by removing the destructuring:

```typescript
export const genKeyId = (length = 5) => Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, length);
```

Alternatively, if you do want it to accept an object but you want it to be able to be called without one, you can default the parameter you're destructuring:

```typescript
export const genKeyId = ({ length = 5 }: GenKeyIdProps = {}) => Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, length);
// −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^
```

Now you can call `genKeyId` A) with an object that has a `length`; B) with an object that doesn't have a `length`; and C) with no argument at all.

It's up to you whether you want `getKeyId` to accept a number or an object with a `length` property.

Comment: Thanks T.J. I want it to accept length as a number  but I still want to type the arguments with an interface. Is that possible?

Comment: @cbutler - No, because interfaces define object types, and a number isn't an object type. That seems like [an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to define the parameters with an interface? (For completeness: You can do it indirectly, by defining a type for `genKeyId` [the function] using `interface` and using that when declaring the constant, [like this](https://tsplay.dev/Nd4PYN), but that would be fairly unusual if `getKeyId` is the only function you need to have this interface, and even then you'd usually use `type` for it.)

Comment: Thanks for X/Y reference, very interesting :) Your explanation makes more sense when I think about how to use the function API. For my use case I think I will use your last suggestion (= {}) as I want to use the default in most cases.

Comment: @cbutler - Just for completeness, the version not using `GenKeyIdProps` at all (the one under *"There's no need for `genKeyId` to accept an object..."* above) also can be called with no arguments, because `length` is defaulted. So `genKeyId()` and `genKeyId(5)` do the same thing.